# Persistent login info from server to server

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am currently working on 2 web servers, One Coldfusion and the other PHP.

Right now, the Coldfusion server is my main server where users log in to access restricted data.
However, I have also begun using a PHP server and want to make it transparent for users to access a specific page on that server - that server requires log in information as well.

I do not want the users to log in twice.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Thx

UPDATE: Working in an Intranet environment, so I can't use any public solution.

UPDATE: Reason I am asking for this is because we are moving from a MSQL / Coldfusion environment (Initial server) to a PHP / ORACLE (new server). So I have 2 user tables as well (although they contain mostly the same information). 
I am trying to faze out the use of our initial server in favor of our new server transparently to the user and thus I have to work in parallel for the time being.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most single-sign-on solutions work a bit like this...

1. Main system authenticates use
2. User opts initiates a need to move to system 2
3. Main system authenticates the user with system 2 in the background
4. System 2 supplies a random, long and disposable token to Main system
5. Main system redirects the user, with the token, to system 2
6. System 2 checks the token (and other factors such as IP address) to validate the session
7. System 2 disposes of the token to ensure it can't be replayed

You would want to ensure that the transmission channels had some security on, especially where Main system and system 2 are talking to each other. You would want that to be a secure transport.

Comment: in the current setup, the login tables are also distinct. Would this still work ?

Comment: You'd need some knowledge of the link - i.e. external userid.

Answer (score 3):

Store sessions in a database, and share them between the two apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [xml-rpc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) to get user data and log the user into the other site when they have a login cookie for the first one and vice versa.

[Php manual page for XML-rpc](http://us.php.net/xmlrpc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an intranet, you can actually sniff out the network username of the user from the PC they are logged into the network on using PHP.  This assumes that:

1. You are using IIS to host your PHP application.
2. Your users are using Windows.

Check the section "2.2 Enabling Support for Detecting Usernames" [here](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/41-Building-a-PHP-5-Web-Server-on-Windows-IIS#2).

After that, all you need to do is investigate if the same is possible from Coldfusion, and you have the basis of an SSO solution based on the network usernames.

Comment: You can do the same in ColdFusion. A cfdump of the CGI variables scope should give all the information one would want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done, in running my own game server, had users on sql server, and on mysql, and wanted to integrate them both.

1. I made sure that if a user was created on 1 system, was also created on the other.
2. So you can modify code in both applications, to automatically create a user in other system if it is created on here.
3. Depending if both servers share a domain, can you do cross-domain sessions or cookies...But my best guess is to store and retreive data...

Or..

1. as a person logins/registers record their current ip address, on both servers, then check if this person was on the other server within 2-5 minutes, if so, use the ip address to identify them....
2. This system is tricky because timing is important, so your not leaving a huge hole in your security....But for short term, going between servers, this is simplest solution, in my own opinion.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing an OpenID solution, much like the one apparent on StackOverflow?

Comment: Ya that would be great, however, I am working in an intranet environment, so all solutions have to be hosted locally. :(

Comment: In that case, as codeburger suggested, you could pass on a login cookie.. 
@sohnee. I dont think so. Because i logged onto my gmail in my laptop and when i open stackoverflow and click on login, its automatically logging in...

Comment: @vinnybozz You could also run an openid provider yourself if you want to (locally)?

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from dropping a shared object on the client machine via Flash or Flex. This object could then be read from ColdFusion/PHP/Python on servers that otherwise had no connection to each other or access to a common database.

Here is a simple example from the Adobe Docs

> Maintain local persistence. This is
>   the simplest way to use a shared
>   object, and does not require Flash
>   Media Server. For example, you can
>   call SharedObject.getLocal() to create
>   a shared object in an application,
>   such as a calculator with memory. When
>   the user closes the calculator, Flash
>   Player saves the last value in a
>   shared object on the user's computer.
>   The next time the calculator is run,
>   it contains the values it had
>   previously. Alternatively, if you set
>   the shared object's properties to null
>   before the calculator application is
>   closed, the next time the application
>   runs, it opens without any values.
>   Another example of maintaining local
>   persistence is tracking user
>   preferences or other data for a
>   complex website, such as a record of
>   which articles a user read on a news
>   site. Tracking this information allows
>   you to display articles that have
>   already been read differently from
>   new, unread articles. Storing this
>   information on the user's computer
>   reduces server load.

Full Information: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/SharedObject.html